# Как сгруппировать числа в пары, которые находятся в списке?

Tags: kotlin

У меня есть вот такой список

```
val valuesToAdd = listOf(18, 73, 44, 6, 33, 22, 7, 5)
```

Как сделать вот такой список `[[18, 73], [44, 6], [33, 22], [7, 5]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val valuesToAdd = listOf(18, 73, 44, 6, 33, 22, 7, 5)
val split = valuesToAdd.withIndex().partition { it.index % 2 == 0 }
val values = split.first.zip(split.second) { a, b -> listOf(a.value, b.value) }
```

Answer (score 3):

Применить функцию [chunked(size: Int)](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html). Разделяет исходный список на подсписки, длиной не более `size`.

```
val valuesToAdd = listOf(18, 73, 44, 6, 33, 22, 7, 5)
val values = valuesToAdd.chunked(2)
```

Comment: Спасибо, причем только дошел в документации до этой функции)